# How few disks are needed to cover a square efficiently?

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling

A unit square can be covered by a single disk of area $\pi/2$. Let us call the ratio of the square's area to that of the covering disks (i.e. the sum of the areas of the disks) the *efficiency* of the covering, so that in the base case with one disk the efficiency is $2/\pi\approx63.66\%$. Say that a covering is *efficient* if its efficiency exceeds this value. If we use a honeycomb (hexagonal) grid of $22$ equal disks in alternating rows of four and five disks, we get a covering efficiency of $24/11\pi\approx69.45\%$; so efficient coverings exist. Allowing disks of different sizes, how few are needed to cover the square efficiently? Can it be done with fewer than $22$ disks?

Comment: this might be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57172/putting-many-disks-in-the-unit-square

Comment: well this looks like solid state chemistry :P

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With a bit of Googling I found this paper: [Covering a Square with up to 30 Equal Circles](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Covering-a-Square-with-up-to-30-Equal-Circles-Nurmela-%C3%96sterg%C3%A5rd/056b67e975ab09fcbece8daa65710cef7d664763), by Kari J. Nurmela and Patric R. J. Östergård.

They used a computer search to find coverings of a square by $n$ equal circles, where the radius of those circles is as small as possible. They give a table of radius values, which I reproduce below. I've added columns with the total area of the circles and the efficiency.

```
  n    radius        Circle Area   Efficiency
  1    0.707106781   1.570796327   0.636619772
  2    0.559016994   1.963495408   0.509295818
  3    0.503891109   2.393010029   0.417883748
  4    0.353553391   1.570796327   0.636619772
  5    0.326160584   1.671024545   0.598435255
  6    0.298727062   1.682093989   0.594497101
  7    0.274291885   1.654526896   0.604402384
  8    0.260300106   1.702897662   0.587234349
  9    0.230636928   1.504007739   0.664890196
  10   0.218233513   1.496210711   0.66835506
  11   0.212516016   1.560723218   0.640728598
  12   0.202275889   1.542479343   0.648306899
  13   0.194312371   1.542034638   0.648493864
  14   0.185510547   1.51361395    0.660670444
  15   0.17966176    1.521081313   0.65742705
  16   0.169427052   1.442897104   0.693050112
  17   0.16568093    1.466033314   0.68211274
  18   0.160639664   1.459244113   0.685286301
  19   0.157841982   1.487128592   0.672436806
  20   0.152246811   1.456385273   0.686631497
  21   0.14895379    1.463768108   0.683168321
  22   0.143693177   1.427068593   0.700737165
  23   0.141244822   1.441527004   0.693708822
  24   0.138302883   1.442193663   0.693388153
  25   0.133548707   1.400777811   0.713889092
  26   0.131764876   1.418151189   0.705143434
  27   0.128633535   1.403531108   0.712488661
  28   0.127317553   1.425884911   0.701318874
  29   0.125553508   1.436169083   0.696296844
  30   0.122036869   1.403631932   0.712437482
```

As you can see, they become efficient from $n=9$ onwards. Here's a picture from that paper of the first efficient arrangements $n=9 ... 12$.

[image]

Of course it may still be possible that with fewer than 9 discs of *different* sizes you can make an efficient covering.

**EDIT**:
Inspired by Jack D'Aurizio's solution I found that you can even make an efficient 3-disc covering.

[image]

Calculating the optimal solution exactly is horrendous. Just by tweaking the numbers, the best efficiency I found with this configuration is approximately $0.693881$.

I chose the large radius to be $0.6572$, and from that it follows that $|OG|=0.426511$, $|AE|=0.179029$, $|AF|=0.146978$, and the small radius is $|EF|/2 = 0.115816$.

**EDIT 2:**

To complete the answer, here is a simple proof that 2 discs can never efficiently cover the square.

Consider the 4 vertices of the square. If one of the discs covers two diagonally opposite vertices, then it will be as large as the 1-disc covering, and the non-zero area of the other disc will make any covering with those discs inefficient.

If either disc covers three of the four vertices, then it will cover a diagonal pair, and the covering becomes inefficient as explained above.

The only way therefore to cover the four vertices is if each disc covers two adjacent vertices. This makes their radii greater than $1/2$. This inequality is easily seen to be strict. Their combined area is then strictly greater than $\pi/2$, making any covering by them inefficient.

Comment: Three looks as though it's going to be hard to beat! I just need to do some checking.

Comment: I get the optimal value for $|AE|$ as the real root of the cubic $6x^3-9x^2+7x-1=0$, with $|AF|=x-x^2$.

Comment: The paper uses *equal* circles. If unequal circles are allowed, the efficiency should never decrease as the number increases, since one could just use fewer circles and "waste" the remainder as circles of zero size.

Comment: @jaapscherphuis hi. can the efficiency be arbitrarily close to 1 with arbitrarily many circles allowed?

Comment: @mathworker21 No, there will always be overlap. I suspect the best covering is a hexagonal arrangement of equal radius circles, which has an efficiency of $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2\pi} \approx 82.699\%$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis "there will always be overlap" doesn't disprove the possibility of being arbitrarily close to $1$

Comment: @mathworker21 Hmm. Thinking about it a bit more, you may be right. You could first pack the area with as many non-overlapping circles as you wanted, reducing the uncovered area to as small you want. Then use as many small circles as you need to cover that area. That second part can be very inefficient, but since it concerns only an arbitrarily small proportion of the whole, the total efficiency may still be arbitrarily close to 1. If you had to use equal sized circles, then I think $82.699\%$ is still the best.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis i don't see the argument as to why you can get arbitrarily close to 1 efficiency. "Then use as many small circles as you need to cover that area". Can't those small circles have very large combined area? Like, the remaining small area can be pretty nasty; it may be due to narrow regions with large diameter and thus not able to be covered nicely by circles.

Comment: @mathworker21 Sure it would need to be proven rigorously, but that is what my intuition tells me. You could use equal-sized circles for that second stage. First do it with a particular choice of radius. Then use half that radius. Then halve it again. The efficiency of this second stage will improve each time you do that. As long as the efficiency of this stage can always be increased to some arbitrary fixed number regardless of the shape of the area, even if it is just 5% efficiency, then we're ok, and I think it does.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I don't agree that "then we're ok", since the process might not stop after finitely many steps, and I insist on having only finitely many circles. (Still, thank you for the continued discussion)

Answer (score 31):

If different circle sizes are allowed, we may reach an efficiency $>76.3\%$ with just five disks:

[image]

With $13$ disks the maximum efficiency is already $>80.4\%$. It is enough to replace each "corner disk" above with three disks with approximately half the radius:

[image]

If we adjust the configuration in each corner (allowing the most external disks to overlap with the larger disk) the maximum efficiency with $13$ disk is $\geq 82.5\%$:

[image]

Comment: Very nice. It looks to me like $12/5\pi$.

Comment: @JohnBentin Yes, I was about to comment the same thing. The distance between the square's vertex and the nearest intersections of the circles is $1/6$.

Comment: Even 3 circles are enough to get efficiency $>2/\pi$: let the big circle pass through two lower vertices of the square and leave two small uncovered "triangles" at the upper vertices; cover those "triangles" with two small circles. But I didn't calculate the maximal efficiency one can obtain this way.

Comment: @Litho I was just doing that too. I added it to my answer, and got an efficiency of $0.693881$.

Comment: Making the corner disks larger and the adjacent disks smaller will allow you to increase the efficiency slightly.

Comment: That last one looks less efficient to me. Is this answer not counting the sum of the areas of all the circles but rather just the area of their union without penalizing overlapping circles?

Comment: @AlexisOlson: less efficient than what? The efficiency is computed as given by the OP, as the ratio between the area of the square and the sum of the areas of the covering circles.

Comment: Less efficient than the previous image.

Comment: @Alexis: how so? The blue circles are shrinking (becoming the purple ones), so the overlapped area decreases and the efficiency increases.

Comment: Oh! I thought you had blue and purple circles. That makes more sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: What's the inscribed dotted circle in the first diagram? Is it used in a construction of the most efficient covering with that count and symmetry?

Comment: A bit off topic, but what did you do the illustrations in? They're beautiful.

Comment: @GregRos: the software I used is just the sponsored www.geogebra.org, it is very useful and practical, I agree. At aschepler: the dotted circle is just the inscribed circle in the original square, I used it for the construction but it is not really relevant there.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio hi. can the efficiency be arbitrarily close to 1 with arbitrarily many circles allowed?

Comment: @mathworker21: that should be true by considering [Apollonian gaskets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket) in a square, by removing all the circles with a small radius and by invoking some form of the Vitali covering Lemma.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks. ill think about it, but am currently skeptical such an argument would work

Comment: I might be wrong, this seems like a difficult packing problem. Even if I am wrong, *what is the limit efficiency?* is an interesting question.